# Are Meshes within Meshes bad?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

The pink spikes seen below are meshes for the model's hair with partical effects and are connected to bones with a damper chain modifier for "bounce".

-Do I have to delete these inside meshes and connect them to the base of the head and or other solution?

-Will these inside meshes be problematic for the unwrapping process?
I am in the process of making this model into an Animaze Avatar.
[image: Pink hair spikes within skull]

Comment: if it currently gives the result you are expecting you don't have to connect them to the head. You can remove the faces that are not visible as they are not useful

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll definitely get rid of some face then, my comp is so slow 

Comment: Intersecting objects are "bad", because the intersections don't get smoothed by the Subdivision Modifier or smooth shading. It may also be problematic for 3D printing, or e.g. unwrapping a papercraft, or unwrapping UV if you intend the color to not change suddenly between the objects. If those and maybe some similar issues are not a problem, then it's not bad.